# SQL Insert values column where values is from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table like this in MySQL, and I want to add values into the `kodeunik` column where the value is a combination of `Kode`, `Daerah` and `NomorKode`

Expected output for `kodeunik` column:

```
Bank BCA       101    00   0003   101000003

Bank BCA PT    101    00   0003   101000001

Bank BNI       101    00   0003   101000004
```

**Question:**

1. How to query like that?
2. Is it possible to make the `kodeunik` as primary key?

Comment: Unless you already make a PRIMARY KEY of `Kode, Daerah, NomorKode`, there's a possibility of duplicates. Are you sure there are no.. or will be no duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do this; you can simply generate the value on the fly:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(Kode, Daerah, NomorKode) AS kodeunik
FROM yourTable
```

or create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW yT_ke AS
    SELECT *, CONCAT(Kode, Daerah, NomorKode) AS kodeunik
    FROM yourTable;
SELECT * FROM yT_ke
```

Output (for both queries):

```
JenisPerkiraan  Kode    Daerah  NomorKode   kodeunik
Bank BCA        101     00      0003        101000003
Bank BCA PT     101     00      0001        101000001
Bank BNI        101     00      0004        101000004
```

If you want a primary key on this combined field, just add it over the 3 columns:

```
 ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Kode, Daerah, NomorKode)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=96d28d880b7b6c45b2949b78c370d75c)

Comment: The OP wants to ** Add values into `kodeunik` column where the value is combination of `Kode`, `Daerah`, `NomorKode` ** instead of selecting as you advice, sir.

Comment: @Anonymous there is rarely any point storing data that can be readily generated on the fly.

Comment: Whether OP wants to have a massive update to his data or not?

Comment: @ryanderon Please take a look at this answer and consider accepting it if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `Update` query to achieve it.

```
    UPDATE your_table_name
    SET kodeunik = concat(`Kode`, `Daerah`, 'NomorKode`)
```

2. If you make sure `kodeunik` value is unique, you can also make it as primary key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @ryanderon

Comment: if I make +, it will sum all of the values because its number, I try with concat

Comment: @Anonymous don't forget to remind the OP to upvote/accept any answer they find useful

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has `CONCAT()` function. In your case, you can try:

```
select CONCAT(Kode, Daerah, NomorKode) from <your_table_name>;
```

If it is what you want, you can use subquery to update them.